# adding libs ONCE for lifetime in autocad 2012

Tags: autocad, cad, autodesk

I am using Autocad 2012. I need to upload libs everytime when I open the Autocad. Is there any way how to avoid this and load libs file by-default when Autocad 2012 is opened?

Please let me know what needs to be done.

Note : some libs are there by-default.

Comment: When you install AC it will ask what libraries to include, I suggest picking all unless you know you'll only be using certain ones. I would suggest that you move any libraries, if not already, into the default lib directories.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.jtbworld.com/lisp/acad_lsp.htm & http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2006/09/automatic_loadi.html